[tag][VTS] Fastbootd related VTS modules are failing
Android version: 13
VTS tool version: 13_r1
Modules Failing :-
FastbootGetvarUserspaceTest
FastbootVerifyUserspaceTest
Issue description:-
My device is Android 13 launch device(with AOSP r24 tag), based on x86_64 architecture. Above mentioned vts modules are failing on my device. My device doesn't have adb over usb support, so i am running vts through adb over ethernet. My device have recovery and fastbootd(fastbootd over tcp) support, so i am running the above mentioned 2 vts fastbootd related modules with adb over ethernet. When i am running these modules, device is entering into fastbootd mode and stuck in it.  In the module invocation, tradefed is rebooting the device to the fastbootd mode by issuing adb reboot fastboot command. After executing this shell command, tradefed is expecting the device state to be in FASTBOOTD mode, but it is getting device state as NOT_AVAILABLE.
Questions i have :-

How tradefed get the device state? By using what interface? I am thinking, as my device doesn't support usb, tradefed will get device state from adb over tcp, Am i right?

Are these failures of FastbootGetvarUserspaceTest & FastbootVerifyUserspaceTest vts modules are expected, if Android device doesn't support adb over usb or fastbootd over usb?

Are these modules pass with fastbootd over tcp support is present?

Is USB support mandatory for the FastbootGetvarUserspaceTest & FastbootVerifyUserspaceTest modules to pass?


Experiment i did:-  From host machine i ran below commands,
adb connect 
adb reboot fastboot [device went to fastbootd mode now]
./fastboot -s tcp: getvar all [got o/p]
With the fastboot executable/tool, i can able to communicate with the device which is in fastbootd mode over tcp, but VTS modules are failing.

Which version of adb and fastboot are you using? It is better to get the ones from platform-tools by Google and add to your path.
